# Testcontainer access external docker network

Tags: docker, testcontainers

I have docker containers running using a network. I run a test which uses BrowserWebDriverContainer, can the testcontainer access the external docker network used by the other docker container, so the testcontainer can access the docker tomcat by name?

Comment: What happens if you try it?  Have you read through https://docs.docker.com/ and its discussion on (bridged) networking setups, and where container DNS names are visible?

Comment: i was able to resolve the issue in the code, after the testContainer is started, to connect it to the external_network used by my other docker containers by running: docker network connect external_network testContainerId